# JQuery UI Resizable with inner jqGrid

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm making a dashboard with small widgets. Widget can be resized with the JQuery UI plugin but only on its height. The width is automatically set to 100% of the parent which is 50% of the screen.

Widget has header and content :

```
<div id="widget">
    <div id="header">ssss</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="grid-container">
            <table id="mygrid"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    var colNames = [
        "One", "Two", "Three", "Four"];
    var colModel = [];
    for (index = 0; index < colNames.length; ++index) {
        colModel.push({
            name: "col" + index,
            id: "col" + index,
            width: 75
        });
    }
    console.log($('#grid-container').height());
    $('#mygrid').jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        data: getData(),
        height: $('#grid-container').height(),
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        colNames: colNames,
        colModel: colModel,
        rownumbers: true,
        rownumWidth: 10,
        scroll: 1
    });

    $('#widget').resizable({
        handles: "s",
        distance: 5,
        alsoResize: "#content",
        resize: function () {
            var $grid = $('#mygrid'),
                $gbox = $grid.find(".ui-jqgrid"),
                outerHeight = $gbox.height() - $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'height') + 24;
            $grid.jqGrid('setGridHeight', $('#grid-container').height() - outerHeight);
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            //that._trigger('resize');
        }
    });
});

function getData() {
    //fake data from http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/T.J.Crowder.htm
    //thx Oleg  
    [...]
}
```

*Fiddle here :*

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/AHWbv/

*Question*

On my site, its laggy and jump when resizing. the fiddle reproduce the issue for me. I'm struggling here if you have any suggestion or alternative solution thx.

**How can I resize my widget HEIGHT with my jqgrid filling the parent when resizing?**

Answer (score 0):

You can call a resize function or tie into the `onresize` event:

```
    //detect if the screen is resized and if so adjust the grids
    window.onresize = function () { resizePageGrids() }
```

and then

```
function resizePageGrids() {        
    var w = $('#widgetContainer').width() - 10;
    $('#gridName').jqGrid('setGridWidth', w, true);
}
```

I added in the `- 10` to account for scroll bars, and a small margin on the grid.

Comment: most of browser have 20px scrolls but it's not what I need here. My width resize work on my version it's the height that crazy

Comment: @TecHunter Boo to not specifying that when asking the question :(

Comment: I Know sorry fixed it